# Post-quantum aggregate / multi signatures

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, cryptocurrency

Are there any practical post-quantum aggregate / multi signatures?
Currently, the aggregate / multi signature schemes seem to be limited to pre-quantum elliptic curve assumptions only, e.g., [[BDN18]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/483.pdf), [[MPSW18]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/068.pdf) and [[Zha18]](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/414.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by practical, but the state-of-the-art lattice-based multi-signatures are the work "Two-round n-out-of-n and Multi-Signatures and
Trapdoor Commitment from Lattices" by Ivan Damgård, Claudio Orlandi, Akira Takahashi, and Mehdi Tibouchi from PKC and JoC 2021: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1110. Also note that the paper "MuSig-L: Lattice-based Multi-Signature with Single-Round Online Phase" by Cecilia Boschini, Akira Takahashi, and Mehdi Tibouchi is accepted at CRYPTO 2022 but is not available online yet. However, these works does not give concrete parameters and have not been implemented yet, but I think it would be an interesting exercise using e.g. the lattice estimator (https://lattice-estimator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and the Number Theory Library (https://libntl.org) to give concrete instantiations of the schemes.